# Android Fresco : Image is not display in SimpleDraweeView if set to the same uri multiple times

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter, fresco

Image is not display in SimpleDraweeView if set to the same uri multiple times. I am getting below logs

```
decoder->decode returned false
decoder->decode returned false
decoder->decode returned false
```

Its printing lots of time

```
<com.test.view.ShadowImageView
            android:id="@+id/fake_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:transitionName="Test"
            app:sl_cornerRadius="3dp"
            app:sl_dx="-2dp"
            app:sl_dy="2dp"
            app:sl_shadowColor="#60000000"
            app:sl_shadowRadius="5dp" />
```

I am creating ShadowImageView with extend SimpleDraweeView and my adapter code is

```
simpleDraweeView.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(new File(mPath)));
```

My Log print

```
D/skia: --- decoder->decode returned false
D/skia: --- decoder->decode returned false
W/unknown:RequestLoggingListener: time 1744951128: onProducerFinishWithFailure: {requestId: 84, stage: DecodeProducer, elapsedTime: -1 ms, extraMap: null, throwable: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException}
W/unknown:RequestLoggingListener: time 1744951128: onRequestFailure: {requestId: 84, elapsedTime: -1 ms, throwable: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException}
D/skia: --- decoder->decode returned false
D/skia: --- decoder->decode returned false
W/unknown:RequestLoggingListener: time 1744953544: onProducerFinishWithFailure: {requestId: 101, stage: DecodeProducer, elapsedTime: -1 ms, extraMap: null, throwable: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException}
W/unknown:RequestLoggingListener: time 1744953545: onRequestFailure: {requestId: 101, elapsedTime: -1 ms, throwable: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException}
```

Comment: You better stop posting the same question several times. Instead, add all the relevant code to your question, in particular how you create the SimpleDrawView (layout xml, Java or both). And provide the image you want to have displayed. With that little information in your question, it's unlikely you ever get an answer.

Comment: I am updated my question . I am doing anything wrong?

Comment: Can you add what the content of `mPath` is?

Comment: That is my local path

Comment: I understand what you want to use it for. But it could be invalid. So please be specific and add it's value to the question. I can't help you if you withhold important information.

Comment: What else information you need...?

Comment: Just set the height of the image view and its working fine.

Comment: I am setting height of the image view in adapter. But it still does not display

Comment: Can you add ControllerListener as explained here: http://frescolib.org/docs/listening-download-events.html#_, and then output the full stack trace from the exception you get in onFailure callback? Just Log.e(TAG, "Fresco Failure", exception).